# Printing json dictionary in aesthetic/readable format in pdf

Tags: python, json, pdf

I have an actual dictionary of latin words. For making a few associations I wish to store their derivatives, etymologies etc. This is for the purpose of taking notes, hence they need to be printed out on a pdf file and therefore need to be readable.

```
{'word' : {'etymology' : 'abcd', 'derivates' : 'ghj', 'etc' : 'etc'}}
```

I will be storing all the information through a json file, however how do I print them to a pdf file such that they are understandable? For example,

Word : **Transformo**

Etymology : **Trans + Formo**

Derivates : **Transformandus**

Or maybe in tables that are in dimension 4x4. Please note the explanation can be of various sizes.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using FPDF to make pdf cells, however, I'd like something more readable, for e.g multiple headings and and multiple level of headings each with different colours.